# Can an Animagus Be Infected With Lycanthropy While In Animal Form?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory, werewolf

Pursuant to [**Why did Remus and Sirius fight in *Prisoner of Azkaban* (Werewolf vs Dog)**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24850/why-did-remus-and-sirius-fight-in-prisoner-of-azkaban-werewolf-vs-dog) I wondered if a human in Animagus form could be infected with lycanthropy if bitten by a werewolf.

An Animagus seems to retain at least some human awareness, as it can turn from human to animal and vice versa at will. Does this mean there is *some* humaness within an Animagus?

**If so, would this mean that an Animagus is vulnerable to lycanthropy, should he or she be bitten while in his/her animal form?**

> As the werewolf reared, snapping its long jaws, Sirius disappeared from Harry’s side. He had transformed. The enormous, bear-like dog bounded forwards. As the werewolf wrenched itself free of the manacle binding it, the dog seized it about the neck and pulled it backwards, away from Ron and Pettigrew. They were locked, **jaw to jaw**, claws ripping at each other –
> <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 279 - Bloomsbury - chapter 20, *The Dementor's Kiss*</sub>

The fact that Sirius did not turn into a werewolf after the above encounter seems to indicate that either Remus didn't actually bite Sirius even though he tried to, or Remus didn't bite Sirius because werewolves prefer and seek out full humans to bite. Or, of course, it could be that Remus *did* bite Sirius, but Animagi are *not* vulnerable to a bite from a werewolf. I suppose it depends on what position of the mouths "jaw to jaw" describes. Nevertheless, I still wonder if an Animagus retains enough of his/her humanity to be at risk from the bite of the werewolf, and therefore lycanthropy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. The entire purpose of them turning into Animagi was that:

> “A werewolf is **only a danger to people**."

Further evidence to this is given when Lupin talks about how they would leave the Shrieking Shack and roam the school grounds, and that Sirius and James:

> transformed into such large animals, they were 
>   **able to keep a werewolf in check**.

This implies that since in order to keep the werewolf "in check" that *large* animals were required, physical assertion was the means by which they kept him in check. Again, the purpose of turning into Animagi was to bypass the threat of being bitten. After Lupin says this, Hermione is quick to explain:

> That was still really 
>   dangerous! ...What if you’d given the others the slip, and 
>   bitten somebody?”

She is worried about Lupin biting someone in the school, and *not* one of the Marauders, further indicating that they were in no danger.

Finally, after the "jaw to jaw" encounter:

> Black was bleeding; there were gashes **across  his muzzle** and back...

Indicating that the "jaw to jaw" caused the gashes across his muzzle, and as you pointed out, he does not change.

Comment: Not sure what good being large would be when the matchup is a stag vs. werewolf. Regular old wolves can give a typical deer a run for its money. But oh well. :P

Comment: @GabeWillard: a single wolf is not guaranteed to defeat a stag. He will probably be kicked in the head by the stag running away, or the stag might even turn and fight the wolf away if cornered. This is why wolves always hunt in packs.

Comment: Even so, wouldn't a werewolf not be considered the equal of a pack of wolves? They're typically depicted as being far superior to the strengths of both the man and beast they are a combination of.

Comment: @GabeWillard Maybe it was a [stag moose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervalces) :). I think the implication though was that it took both Sirius and James to quell Lupin, which probably accounts for the apparent disparity.

Comment: A single wolf wouldn't even be a threat to a stag. A stag would just aim it's prongs at the wolf and the wolf would be to smart to come closer. Werewolves are generally stronger, but Sirius and James together can double-team the werewolf, of course, and probably easily restrain it.

Comment: @GabeWillard in book canon (as opposed to the film representation) a werewolf is simply a wolf when transformed.