# If a werewolf would become an Animagus, would he still transfrom by the full moon?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf, animagi, remus-lupin

All of Lupin's friends became Animagi to help him during his transformation, as Animagi cannot be affected by werewolf bites.

However, what would've happened had Lupin himself had became an Animagus? During a full moon while in his animal form, would he have still transformed into a werewolf, or would he have stayed in in his animal form?

Comment: Prepare yourself for a "we don't know" anwer.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Animagus Part of the proces by which one becomes an Animagus is holding the leaf of a mandrake in their mouth for an entire month, using the leaf for the creation of a potion, and reciting an incantation (Amato Animo Animato Animagus) on a daily basis. As source is cited 2014 UK version of the books. That being said Lupin would not be able to undertake the proces in the first place.

Comment: But that does not answer the case where established Animagi was bitten by Werewolf in a human form. But that scenario would be unlikely as the wizard would probably try to morph when he'll meet a Werewolf.

Comment: @doomista Werewolves don't attack animals, so that makes sense. Apart from Fenrir Greyback, of course...

Comment: Why wouldn't lupin be able to undertake the process? Just use a sticking charm inside his cheek to keep the leaf there, and charm it imperturbable.

Comment: @doomista - The wiki cites the wrong source as usual, [as you can see here](http://nickblackford.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/book6-1-2.png), only part of that information was in the 2014 UK Childrens books. The actual source is one of the paywalled Pottermore writings.

Comment: @DanielB - There are some things which need to be done during the full moon.

Comment: Looking over the parts necessary to do during the full moon according to the wiki, I'm pretty sure the bit about spitting out the leaf would be doable. And if you have friends, they can handle the other bits.

Comment: @DanielB - It's unknown whether friends doing parts would work. Rowling seemed to be pretty clear that deviating slightly from the ten steps could cause serious harm. Also, the nightly wand stuff for a few months would need to be done by oneself.

Comment: Related: [Can an Animagus Be Infected With Lycanthropy While In Animal Form?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24856/31394)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Lupin's werewolf transformations would have interfered with him becoming an Animagus.

Becoming an Animagi is a long process which requires things to be done on a daily basis, including nights of a full moon.

> Talent in both Transfiguration and Potions is necessary to become an Animagus. No responsibility can be taken for any physical or mental problems resulting from following these instructions.
>
> 1. **For the space of one entire month** (from full moon to full moon), a single leaf from a Mandrake must be carried constantly in the mouth. The leaf must not be swallowed or taken out of the mouth at any point. If the leaf is removed from the mouth, the process must be started again.
> 2. **Remove the leaf at the full moon** and place it, steeped in your saliva, in a small crystal phial that receives the pure rays of the moon (if the night is cloudy, you will have to find a new Mandrake leaf and begin the whole process again). To the moon-struck crystal phial, add one of your own hairs, a silver teaspoon of dew collected from a place that neither sunlight nor human feet have touched for a full seven days, and the chrysalis of a Death’s-head Hawk Moth. Put this mixture in a quiet, dark place and do not look at it or otherwise disturb it until the next electrical storm.
> 3. While waiting for the storm, the following procedure should be followed **at sunrise and sundown.** The tip of the wand should be placed over the heart and the following incantation spoken: ‘Amato Animo Animato Animagus.’
> 4. The wait for a storm **may take weeks, months or even years.** During this time, the crystal phial should remain completely undisturbed and ...
>
> `[there are a total of ten steps listed]`
>
> <sub>[Pottermore - Animagi](https://usd.shop.pottermore.com/products/short_stories_from_hogwarts_of_heroism_hardship_and_dangerous_hobbies_ebook_english) (behind paywall)</sub>

**Seeing as Lupin's furry little problem would keep him otherwise occupied during these times, he would not be able to become an Animagus.**

Comment: what he was a Animagus before he was bitten.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier - that would be a whole new question, and you should feel free to ask it.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier - No he wasn't.

Comment: And so they thought he had a troublesome bunny.

Comment: What about the Wolfsbane potion? Couldn't he keep the leaf in his mouth then?

Answer (score 3):

If Lupin had become an Animagus, he would still have transformed by the full moon. Recall that Hermione recites the book, saying that a werewolf has no control over his transformations, meaning that he must change no matter what. So he would change in his Animagus form, yes. Of course, he might only transform by losing the tail.

Comment: Sorry it's short.

Answer (score -3):

Werewolf will be rejected to become an Animagus, because becoming an Animagus must have undergone a long process to achieve, since in Harry Potter World, Werewolf would be forced to transform once a month during the full moon, it doesn't meet the requirements of transforming into a Animagus. By the way, Werewolf's animal form is only their wolf form during the full moon.

Comment: The accepted answer already says this.